# saving php variables to script variables in a function

Tags: javascript, php, function, variables

Let's say I have 100 rows of php-variables that I want to save to javascript variables.

```
 $data1;
 $data2;
 $data3;
 $data4;
 ...
 $data99;
 $data100;
```

How can I save those variables in a function so I don't have to save it manually like:

```
var data1 = '<?php echo $data1; ?>';
...
```

Would be very great if it can be solved. So much work otherways :/

Answer (score 2):

pack them into an object, then use

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($your_object); ?>;
```

Comment: How do I do that? Pretty new to this @adassko

Answer (score 2):

Doesnt work. PHP is serverside, javascript clientside. When the JS is initialised, PHP is done with its work. But you can either use AJAX or do a for-loop and write the javascript with PHP.

```
echo "<script>";
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){ 
    echo "var data" . $i " = " . $data1 .";";
}
echo "</script>";
```

Untested.

Comment: This would echo the same variable 100 times.

Comment: you probably meant `${'data' . $i'}` and `for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)`

Comment: arf, yes, of course, just created a fast code without thinking.^^

Comment: will try it :) @YUNOWORK

Comment: Is this right?  echo "var data" . $i " = " . ${'data' .$i}. "; ";   It gives me just errors. @Adassko

Comment: @PeterP: you are missing a dot after first `$i`

Answer (score 1):

If your variables are like the ones you posted and the number of variables is known you you could simply do:

```
$num_vars = 50;

for($i=0; $i < 50; $i++) {
   $tmp_var = "$data$i";
   if (is_numeric($tmp_var)) {
      echo "var myVar$i = $tmp_var;\n";
   } else {
      echo "var myVar$i = '$tmp_var';\n";
   }
}
```

Keep in mind the use of double quotes. PHP recognizes variables in double quotes. Also test if it is a number or a string as shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in an array and then with a php for loop populate a javascript array with the values.

Answer (score 0):

create an array of variables and then try to use `json_encode`

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data['data1']);
```